# Does list contains item with specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have list of elements. 
What is the best way to check if this list contains element with value = 0?

```
<ul>
<li><input type="hidden" value="0" name="Locations.Locations[0].LocationId" id="Locations_Locations_0__LocationId" class="selected-id"></li>
<li><input type="hidden" value="1" name="Locations.Locations[1].LocationId" id="Locations_Locations_1__LocationId" class="selected-id"></li>
<li><input type="hidden" value="2" name="Locations.Locations[2].LocationId" id="Locations_Locations_2__LocationId" class="selected-id"></li>
</ul>
```

In example - check if ul contains element with value = 0.

I try use `$('li input.selected-id').each()..`
where i check every element value, but i don't think it's the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select that particular `li` by using `:has()` along with `attribute selector`.

Try,

```
$('li:has(input[value=0])')
```

Please read **[here](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** to know more about `:has()` selector

Comment: thanks for reply. i use your sample in my project, but this sample returns element and not bool value. Is it my fault? `var isSelectedAll = $('.added-items-data:has(input[value=0])', ctrlContext);` - my code

Comment: @user3296938 it wont return a boolean value, if you want to check that you can use like `$('li:has(input[value=0])').length > 0`

Comment: i can't use selector in contex with :has selector?

Comment: @user3296938 Pardon.?

Comment: i can select class .selected-id in context of ul as `$('selected-id','ul')`... can i do it also while using :has selector? maybe this is why i get object instead of bool

Comment: @user3296938 No, `:has()` is a kind of filter, actually i was confused about the same while i was learning it. You can get a clear idea after reading the documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li input.selected-id').each(function(){
   return $(this).val() == 0;
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but as i wrote before, i don't think it is best solution

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways.

There's the `:has` pseudo-class that jQuery adds:

```
var theLi = $("ul li:has(input[value=0])");
```

...but it has the disadvantage that jQuery can't hand the query off to the browser's built-in selector engine.

You can do it like this:

```
var theLi = $("ul input[value=0]").closest("li");
```

...which doesn't use any jQuery selector additions, but does take two steps.